# Angular - How to access to child component from grandparent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a componentA that has an ng-content. After this I have a componentB inside the component A. The componentB has a componentC in his template.

componentA template:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

componentB template:

```
<componentC></componentC>
```

componentC template:

```
<div>
  <span>test</span>
<div>
```

In my html I have this final solution:

```
<componentA>
 <componentB></componentB>
</componentA>
```

I would use a viewChild inside the componentA to find componentC that's inside componentB but it returns undefined

```
@ViewChild(ComponentC) componentC: ComponentC
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Best way to do this is with services, https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Answer (score 1):

In service:

```js
private sharedValue = new BehaviorSubject('Initial value')
currentSharedValue = this.sharedValue.asObservable()

changeSharedValue(newValue: string) {
  this.sharedValue.next(newValue)
}
```

*If you don't want to set an initial value you can use a regular Subject and if you want to track history a ReplaySubject.*

Component changing data:

```js
constructor(
  private dataService: DataService
) { }

changeSharedData(): void {
  this.dataService.changeSharedValue('New Shared Data')
}
```

Component reading shared data:

```js
value = 'Old Value'
subscription!: Subscription;

constructor(
  private dataService: DataService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.dataService.currentSharedValue.subscribe(newValue => {
    this.value = newValue
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: Very neat solution, I have adapted this approach before myself but in complex scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different way , let parent component points to child !

So assuming ComponentA is parent of ComponentB inside your HTML

```
<ComponentA><ComponentB></ComponentB></ComponentA>
```

So in ComponentA ts define a public variable of ComponentB

```
myComponent: ComponentB;
```

At ComponentB constructor inject ComponentA

`constructor(parent:ComponentA) { parent.myComponent = this; }`

now parent ComponentA can access child componentB